# Why a phrase is getting searched against default fields in solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

This might be a very silly question but i want to know why this is happening.
If i am using edismax query parser in solr and passing query something like below

```
q=IPhone5&wt=xml&edismax=true&qf=Product-Name-0^100&bq=(Product-Rating-0%3A7^300+OR+Product-Rating-0%3A8^400+OR+Product-Rating-0%3A9^500+OR+Product-Rating-0%3A10^600+OR+Product-Rating-0%3A*)
```

Then why it is searching in default fields ?
As i am specifying qf,it should search in the fields specified in qf parameter and boost those documents which has a higher rating.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
Note:-I am using SOLR 4.0 Alpha

Thanks,
Pragyanshis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes with the RequestHandler like below.

1.Added defType =  edismax

```
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
```

2.Removed default field .

Now it is working as i expected.